# Is there a way to track which links Telegram users are clicking on to join a group?

Tags: hyperlink, telegram

I would like to set up invite links to be able to track which specific links are driving more traffic to a Telegram group. For example, if we have a link to a Telegram group on a Twitter page and another on our website, could we track which link was being used to bring new people into the group?

Comment: Yes, make a unique link for everyone on your own domain and store in a database whenever each link is opened.